# Simulation for cose and spread layout (cytoscape.js)

Tags: layout, cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape.js and I added layouts to application (continuous and normal ones). For normal ones (like circle, random, concetrici etc) animation is working great. I know that continuous layouts are based on simulation in real-time. It is working nice for springy layout, but (for the same data) cose layout and spread layout simulation is not visible (or not working, but I think that it is that fast that is computed before page is fully loaded). Is there any possibilty to slow it down, for simulation/animation to be visible? I was reading documentation and trying change settings (animationThreshold, maxSimulationTime, initialTemp, maxFruchtermanReingoldIterations, maxExpandIterations) but it is not helping. 
Here are examples with config values.

for spread layout:

```
expandingFactor: -1.0
maxFruchtermanReingoldIterations: 20
maxExpandIterations: 20
animate: true
maxSimulationTime: 5000
randomize: false
```

and for cose:

```
animationThreshold: 2500
animate: true
nodeRepulsion: (node) ->
    400000
gravity: 80
numIter: 1000
initialTemp: 200
coolingFactor: 0.99
minTemp: 1.0
randomize: false
maxSimulationTime: 50000
```

Thanks for help, 

 Izabella

Answer (score 1):

Force-directed / physics simulations layouts run/animate in real time.  Artificially slowing one down would spread it out but also make it really choppy.

[CoSE-Bilkent](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cose-bilkent) has `animate: 'end'` support.  That feature, assuming that the end result of the layout is generated near instantly, animates from the start positions to the end positions with the Cytoscape.js animation APIs.  This gives a similar effect to a discrete layout.

The bundled CoSE will have `animate: 'end'` support in 3.2.  If you want to see the feature in other layout extensions, feel free to make a pull request (maybe based on [CoSE-Bilkent's approach](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cose-bilkent/blob/1.6.14/src/Layout/index.js#L271)).

Comment: Thank you for reply, I used CoSE-Bilkent instead of Cose, it is working perfectly! :)